I'm getting an `Unreachable code` warning in my function block
I am getting an Unreachable code warning in the following function block:
    /**
     * @notice Follows CEI (checks, effects, interactions)
     * @param tokenCollateralAddress The address of the token to deposit as collateral
     * @param amountCollateral The amount of collateral to deposit
     */
    function depositCollateral(address tokenCollateralAddress, uint256 amountCollateral)
        external
        isAllowedToken(tokenCollateralAddress)
        moreThanZero(amountCollateral)
        nonReentrant
    {
        s_collateralDeposited[msg.sender][tokenCollateralAddress] += amountCollateral;
        emit CollateralDeposited(msg.sender, tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);

        bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountCollateral);
        if (!success) {
            revert DSCEngine__TransferFailed();
        }
    }

my modifiers are as follows:
    modifier isAllowedToken(address token) {
        if (s_priceFeeds[token] == address(0)) {
            revert DSCEngine__NotAllowedToken();
        }
        _;
    }

    modifier moreThanZero(uint256 amount) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            revert DSCEngine__NeedsMoreThanZero();
            _;
        }
    }

import {ReentrancyGuard} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

I've checked the code and also asked AI and it should be reachable.
the whole contract code is in the following github link:
https://github.com/smahdi-dev/defi-stablecoin/blob/main/src/DSCEngine.sol

Move the _; in your moreThanZero modifier outside the if block, as it's saying to execute the rest of the code after revert, thereby making it unreachable.
So, your moreThanZero modifier definition should be like this:
modifier moreThanZero(uint256 amount) {
    if (amount == 0) {
        revert DSCEngine__NeedsMoreThanZero();
    }
    _;
}


what a dummy thing I did wrong. thank you very much.

It happens with all of us. You're welcome.
